# resize content tableview custom obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have to solve this problem, as you can see from the photo.

[image]

If I click on one of the two lines, the icon pops up and the `label` and `imageView` gets smaller.

I must be able to select and deselect without the content being reduced.

I'm trying with `sizeToFit` but without success...

The other thing is that I use the custom .xib in this way

```
-(MultiIbanTableCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *idCell = @"MultiIbanTableCell";

    MultiIbanTableCell *cell;
    DtoInstrument *account = (DtoInstrument *)[self.bankSelected.dtoBank.instruments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idCell];

    if (cell) {
        [cell setBankCellWithBankData:account];
    }
    else {
        cell = [MultiIbanTableCell getBankCellWithBankData:account];

    }

    [cell.logoImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.bankSelected.logo_search]
                      placeholderImage:nil
                             completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {
                             }];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.contentView.sizeToFit;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //link store vuoto
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.selectedInstrument = (DtoInstrument *)[self.bankSelected.dtoBank.instruments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.confirmButton.enabled = YES;
    tableView.sizeToFit;
}
```

Comment: There's no photo in the question (?)

Comment: @MatteoPacini There is  link "XIB" after code :)

Comment: What you are seeing is by design. Easiest way to avoid that (since you're using a custom cell anyway) is to use a `UIImageView` with your own selected / unselected checkmark images instead of the `.accessoryType`

Comment: @DonMag mm ok I understood the problem. how can i shine? do I have to work on the costraints?

Comment: @Stefano -- are you currently using a custom cell, or a standard cell? If custom, can you show an image of your prototype cell?